# Remove "0" before decimals number in tables in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

Remove "0" before decimal number in Tables using "siunitx" package, please refer highlighted portions for your references and my MWE file as below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}S[table-format=1.2,group-four-digits=false,
round-integer-to-decimal=false,]
              *{4}{S[table-format=2.2]}
              *{2}{S[table-format=3.2]}@{}}
\toprule
$\varphi$ & a & $\xi$ & $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & ${\dot{W}}^{M1}$ & ${\dot{W}}^{M2}$ \\
\midrule
{Abcde} & .00 & .48 &  .02 &  .17 & 250.00 & 250.00 \\
.10 & .50 & .21 & .82 & .39 & 236.86 & 236.72000 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good question for understanding how to use `siunitx`, but I suggest keeping the leading zero for most uses. It's really easy to lose the leading decimal due to a bad print job/photocopy/scan, or for it to be overlooked even in a good one. At a cost of one character's width, the added zero makes the value more clear. The only time the zero isn't useful is when the type of value is known to be less than one (as is sometimes the case for statistics) and values are printed in tabular form (as is done here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of `add-integer-zero=false` and a correcter `table-format` of the last column:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\sisetup{add-integer-zero=false}
\begin{tabular}{@{}S[table-format=1.2]
              *{4}{S[table-format=2.2]}
              S[table-format=3.2]
              S[table-format=3.5]@{}}
\toprule
$\varphi$ & a & $\xi$ & $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & ${\dot{W}}^{M1}$ & ${\dot{W}}^{M2}$ \\
\midrule
{Abcde} & .00 & .48 &  .02 &  .17 & 250.00 & 250.00 \\
.10 & .50 & .21 & .82 & .39 & 236.86 & 236.72000 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Leandriis, which is I am looking for.

Comment: You could also adjust the column format to reflect that there is no longer an integer portion (table-format=0.2) if centered headings are desired.

Comment: The `add-integer-zero` option is dropped from the latest releases. Is there any replacement for it? I tried `minimum-integer-digits = 0` but this doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: For me the following did work: `print-zero-integer = false`.