# How to remove zeroes before decimal numbers in tables with siunitx -- revisited

Tags: pdftex, siunitx, ubuntu

Due to style guidelines for a journal, I need to remove the zeros before the decimals.

Apparently, the option `add-integer-zero=false` provided in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513066/136969) was removed from `siunitx`. Is there an update or workaround?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\sisetup{add-integer-zero=false}
\begin{tabular}{@{}S[table-format=1.2]
              *{4}{S[table-format=2.2]}
              S[table-format=3.2]
              S[table-format=3.5]@{}}
\toprule
$\varphi$ & a & $\xi$ & $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & ${\dot{W}}^{M1}$ & ${\dot{W}}^{M2}$ \\
\midrule
{Abcde} & .00 & .48 &  .02 &  .17 & 250.00 & 250.00 \\
.10 & .50 & .21 & .82 & .39 & 236.86 & 236.72000 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

*Using:*

- pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)
- siunitx 2022-02-02 v3.0.46

Answer (score 4):

For v3 I tighened up the options: the one you want here relates to printing, so is now called `print-zero-integer` (set `false`).

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, gives me `! LaTeX3 Error: The key 'siunitx/print-zero-integer' is unknown and is being
(LaTeX3)        ignored.` though

Comment: This works with `siunitx` v3.1.9, last revised 2022-10-23. Try to upgrade your `siunitx` installation.

Comment: I overwrote `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty` with the new version, compiles now with `siunitx 2022-10-23 v3.1.9`. No error anymore but still seeing zeroes.